Given the "Full faith and credit" clause, how can some states not accept CCW permits from other states?
It seems to me that the same way the FF&C clause forces the states to all accept each other's driver's licenses, marriages, etc they would need to accept every handgun permit as well.  But I know NY for example refuses permits from many other states.
What's going on here?

Frame challenge: A lot of different licenses and certifications are not immediately transferable between states. Contractor licenses, accounting, legal professions, medical, even realtors. Driver licenses require to be exchanged when residency changes, etc. Marriage certificate denotes one's status which doesn't change when crossing borders (one is still married) and is an evidence of an event (similarly - birth certificates), but everything else... is not at all all that easily accepted. Why would guns be treated differently?

@littleadv I don't need to get an NY drivers license to drive through NY from PA, I only need to get an NY license if I move my residence there.  Why is the same not true of handgun permits?  If anything, considering the fact that driving on public roads is a privilege, not a right, I would expect this situation to be reversed.  You DO have a right to bear arms.

Just as a counterpoint, while states will generally accept each other's marriage licenses, that is not guaranteed.  "Under traditional conflict of laws rules, states have the right to
refuse to recognize marriages celebrated in another state or country, if
that marriage is contrary to the forum state's strong public policy. " ( https://scholarship.law.umn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1204&context=faculty_articles).  Today, that would really only apply to things like marriages to very young people that are allowed in one state but not in most others.

@Ryan_L no, if you did you wouldn't need a permit. You don't.

"I don't need to get an NY drivers license to drive through NY from PA, I only need to get an NY license if I move my residence there": this isn't necessarily because of the full faith and credit clause.  Do you know of any federal court decision that held that the recognition of out-of-state driver's licenses is required by the clause?  Maybe it's just a consequence of the interstate Driver License Agreement.  "Public acts" such as birth certificates, marriage certificates, and court orders, are in a different category from licenses.

There's a case currently on appeal before the Massachusetts Supreme Judicial Court that addresses two separate but similar arrests of NH residents with NH CCW permits in MA without a MA LTC. The NH Attorney General has filed amicus briefs. More at: https://www.doj.nh.gov/news-and-media/new-hampshire-files-brief-supporting-legal-challenge-application-massachusetts-gun

The same thing with marriages applies to drivers licenses. States will apply different rules, in particular, for drivers from a different state who are younger than the visited state's minimum driving age, and restricted drivers licenses issued e.g. because of a DUI conviction.

Driver's licenses aren't acknowledged under this clause, though.  That's just a mutual agreement among the states that they don't want their residents being inconvenienced by not having their license recognized as sufficient for travel and identification, so they agree not to inconvenience anyone else to secure the convenience for themselves. If the states were generally all of the mind that other licenses should also be universally recognized, they could almost surely do so.  But they don't.  So they don't.

A concealed carry permit is a right to possess a firearm within a state that issues one. It is not a right to possess a firearm everywhere, which is beyond the jurisdiction of a state government to do.
In the same way, a license to practice medicine in one state is not a licenses to practice medicine in another state.
Reciprocal driver's license recognition is not a function of the full faith and credit clause of the constitution. It is statutory.
Marriage is a legal status of a person, which is a different from a right to do something in a state.

Is there any other right enumerated in the U.S. Constitution that only ripens if the citizen begs leave of the state to exercise that right, pays a fee in the currency of the realm for the privilege of asking, and waits for a time while the state considers the request before leave to exercise that right is bestowed upon the citizen?

"Marriage is a legal status of a person" so is a pistol permit.  In fact so is the other license you said doesn't transfer.  A pistol permit says this person has the status of being trustworthy with a pistol in public.  A license to practice medicine says this person has the status of being trained to be a doctor.  "CCW Holder" is just as much of a status as "Married".

@Ryan_L CCW Holder is not a legal status.

@MTA Yes. Most of them.

@ryan_l There is political pressure for SCOTUS to force marriages to be recognized by other states.  There isn't (as much) for the other examples.

@IllusiveBrian Full faith and credit has applied to marriage for centuries.

@Ryan_L It should be, but right now it isn't. The law is still behind on recognizing the right to concealed carry on the same level as guns, liberty, and the fursuit of happiness.

@ohwilleke indeed, this was infamously the case in Gretna Green, Scotland, a destination for many years for eloping couples from England looking for a quick marriage that would be recognized back home but would not require the more onerous procedure to get married on English soil.

@RobertColumbia This is a very old practice in Scotland v. England and was the source of lots of U.S. choice of law rules for marriage and divorce.

@ohwilleke also plenty of cases of it being ignored historically when what was an 'acceptable' marriage was in dispute. And the fact all states recognise each others definition of marriage isn't full faith and credit. Its because the definition of a valid marriage is set by federal statute. And there's not federal statue defining what a concealed carry permit is. So there's a reasonable argument that following this would at best only allow CCW permits to be exercised as an equivalent permit issued by the state would. Assuming the state does at all

@user1937198 "the fact all states recognise each others definition of marriage isn't full faith and credit." it most certainly is full faith and credit and is not simply a matter of federal or state statutes.
